# Problem with Java Faces and h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a Modal form with three combos:

```xml
<h:panelGrid columns="3" id="parameterLabels" >
    <h:outputText id="lblCdrType" styleClass="formLabel" value="#{BRulesConfig.lblParameter307}:" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="cmdCdrType" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size: 14px; width:240px ;"
                     value="#{BRulesConfig.cdrType}" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="-Select One-" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <f:selectItems id="lstCdrType" value="#{BRulesConfig.cdrTypeList}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{BRulesConfig.changeStatus}"
                     reRender="parameterValuesPanelTypeModule,parameterValuesPanelFields,pnlValuesPar,formMessage,formErrMessage,formErrorNew,formInfoNew"
                     ajaxSingle="true" status="idLoading" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="parameterValuesPanelTypeModule"  >
    <h:outputText id="lblCdrTypeModule" styleClass="formLabel" value="#{BRulesConfig.lblParameter307_output}:" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="cmdCdrTypeModule" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size: 14px; width:240px ;"
                     value="#{BRulesConfig.parameterValueBean.id_output}"  >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="-Select One-" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <f:selectItems id="lstCdrTypeModule" value="#{BRulesConfig.cdrTypeModules}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" status="idLoading" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="parameterValuesPanelFields"  >
    <h:outputText id="lblCdrTypeModuleField" styleClass="formLabel" value="#{BRulesConfig.lblParameter307_field}: #{BRulesConfig.parameterValueBean.value}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="cmdCdrTypeModuleField" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size: 14px; width:240px ;"
                     value="#{BRulesConfig.parameterValueBean.value}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="-Select One-" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <f:selectItems id="lstCdrTypeModuleField" value="#{BRulesConfig.cdrTypeModulesField}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>                                                                          
</h:panelGrid>
```

Everything is fine and is loading perfectly.

The first combo `cmdCdrType` uses ajax to load the second combox `cmdCdrTypeModule`. It does so using the `onchange` event (`a4j:support`). This is also true for the third combobox: `cmdCdrTypeModule`.

I don't have any problem using any of these combos. But when I try to save all the info that I have stored, I receive the following error message sent by Faces:

```
28-jul-2011 18:04:51 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase execute
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=frm307:cmdCdrTypeModuleField[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(frm307:cmdCdrTypeModuleField: Error de Validación: Valor no es correcto.), detail=(frm307:cmdCdrTypeModuleField: Error de Validación: Valor no es correcto.)]
```

Translating the last line:

```
Error de Validacion :Valor no es Correcto 
Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

I tried using a converter class, but the same error is displayed. I tried changing my beans setters but nothing changes. My faces config looks like this:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>BRulesConfig</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.tsb.mediation.brules.configuration.BRulesConfigurationControl</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I don't know why I'm receiving this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Validation Error : Value is not correct -- is not a converter error but validator error. Do you use custom objects in the drop down? If yes, then you need to overwrite equals() and hashCode() on the custom object.

Comment: I dont use custom objects. I use SelecItem class.

Answer (score 0):

During the apply request values phase of the form submit request, JSF will re-obtain the list of select items from the bean to compare the selected value against the list in order to prevent the server side against spoofed/tampered submits. If no one of the items `equals()` the selected value, then you will get this error.

It look like that the bean is request scoped and/or that you're doing business in the getter. You need to put the bean in the view scope (or when you're using JSF 1.x, the `<a4j:keepAlive>` on the bean) and move all business logic outside the getters to get it to work properly.

Comment: I like your anserw. emailing with other people, the same problem with selectOneMenu component they have. They recommend me change to richcombobox component and it just work perfectly. Thanks a lot !!